# Word 2007 changes all dots between digits to commas when typing Arabic

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007

In Microsoft Word 2007, while typing in Arabic, all dots between digits change to commas.

I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Word tries to be smart and does an auto-replace assuming you meant the thousandths separator, or a decimal point.  You'll need to either `edit - undo` the auto-correct, or disable the auto-correct feature: `Office - Word Options - Proofing - AutoCorrect Options`

Comment: I cannot find anything related to decimal separators in those settings, but neither do I encounter the problem in the first place, on MS Word, on Win 7 Pro, Finnish versions. So I suppose this depends on Word language version.